# How to mix more than 10 RSS feeds?

Tags: php, javascript, rss

I just want to mix around 10 rss feeds into one and then i want to filter the results as per my requirements.

I know we can use yahoo pipes like solution for this,but due to some reasons i do not want to use yahoo's facility so is their any open source solution which i can host on my server and mix feeds using it.

I am using PHP for development along with Javascript(jquery).

Can i do this using simplepie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use SimplePie.  `set_feed_url()` accepts an array, and will combine all of them for you automatically.

```
$feed = new SimplePie();
$feed->set_feed_url(array('your','urls','here'));
```

Comment: do you any other solution,i mean other than simple pie

Comment: @Peeyush, if SimplePie doesn't meet your needs, you should specify why in your question.  Sure, there are 1000 ways to do this, but the right answer depends on why you want something else.

Comment: ok then let me try this first then i will tell you accordingly...anyways thanks for the answer & comments